# Source for Full Text of 1875 French Constitutional Laws

Tags: constitution, history, france

After some frustrating research, I have still failed to find a full English text of the 1875 French constitutional laws. Where can I find it, or where is a good place to continue searching?

Comment: I know it is not the question, but, for the record, the text in French is at http://www.conseil-constitutionnel.fr/conseil-constitutionnel/francais/la-constitution/les-constitutions-de-la-france/constitution-de-1852-second-empire.5107.html and a scan is available at http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5688240b/f65.image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following at https://archive.org/details/constitutionsoth00andeiala : "The constitutions and other select documents illustrative of the history of France, 1789-1901", by Anderson, Frank Maloy, 1871-1961.